# Concurrency and slice iteration

Tags: concurrency, iteration, go

I have a read-only slice of objects of a certain type.

A lot of concurrent goroutines will iterate over this slice to find a certain object in it and use it.

This slice is strictly read-only, it is written to only once (when the application is launched) and then never again.

Will concurrent goroutines interfere with each other when iterating over the slice? (Do I need to apply a read-lock?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, as long as the slice is read-only, there's no problem. Reading a slice does not mutate it.